# Windows Forms - Powershell - MouseHover event on PictureBox/TextBox

Tags: events, powershell, picturebox, mousehover

I made a GUI using windows forms. Just wondering if it is possible to add a mousehover event for picture boxes (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox).

A quick workaround I had made is to create invisible buttons where the picture boxes are and add .add_mousehover and .add_mouseleave events on that button. Rather messy, really.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the add_mousehover tho your System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox object.

```
$test = {MSG * 1}
$pictureBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$pictureBox1.add_mousehover($test)
```

Comment: Thanks bud! Actually tried that out earlier and found that it wasn't working as intended. Turns out I had assigned the event on another picture box and was highlighting the other one. Haha.